# Count down from 10 to 0: just displays -201

Tags: little-man-computer

```
LOOP    LDA COUNT
        SUB 1
        STA COUNT
        OUT 
        BRA PROGEND
        HLT
COUNT   DAT 11
ONE     DAT 1
```

To me it seems pretty basic and simple and in my knowledge of maths, it should work: evidently it is not.

So help pls

Comment: It is inline on my lmc, i just didn't know how to format :D

Comment: This isn't valid code as written: PROGEND is undefined (perhaps it should be LOOP?) and even fixing that, the code will run forever (perhaps BRA should be BRP?)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this code:

- `SUB` does not accept a literal number as argument. The argument is an address, and so in your case it should read `SUB ONE` instead of `SUB 1`.
- The label `PROGEND` is not defined, so this code should not even assemble. Given the meaning of the label, the label should be defined in the line with `HLT`, but that does not make sense, as `HLT` is anyway the next instruction, making the `BRA` obsolete.
- The label `LOOP` is never referenced.
- If `BRA` was intended to refer to the `LOOP` label, then your code would be in for an infinite loop, as `BRA` jumps unconditionally. Your code should have a conditional branch instruction somewhere (either `BRP` or `BRZ`), so there is a way to either repeat the loop or to end it.

Here is how it could work:

```html
LOOP    LDA COUNT
        OUT 
        SUB ONE
        STA COUNT
        BRP LOOP
        HLT
COUNT   DAT 10
ONE     DAT 1

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.6/lmc.js"></script>
```